# How to get the data from Advanced Custom Fields with sub group

Tags: wordpress, grouping, advanced-custom-fields

I can't import the data to top page(front-page.php) with ACF. I tried to write code like this. But I couldn't. Please tell me how to get the data with ACF.

Field name: left-result
Firled type: group
sub field: left-title

```
   <?php if (have_rows('left-result')) : ?>
        <li>
            <?php while (have_rows('left-result')) : the_row(); 
              $t_ttl = get_sub_field('left-title');
            ?>
            <h1><?php echo $t_ttl; ?></h1>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you getting the `<li>` element? because if not, you are not hitting your acf group. If you are not inside the loop, then you need to specify the ID to ACF. `have_rows('left-result', get_the_ID())`

Comment: Can you share your ACF code via Custom fields > Tools > Export File?

Comment: I got my file but how to share you it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use unique key rather than `field_name`:

```sql
if( have_rows('parent_field') ):
        while ( have_rows('parent_field') ) : the_row();
            $sub_value = get_sub_field('sub_field');
            // Do something...
        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
```

[image: Field_key Example JPEG]

Comment: It doesn't have the key. It have name and type.

Comment: In your Dashboard go to Custom Fields > Custom Fields, and choose your field group.
    Click 'Screen Options' at the top right of your browser window.
    Set 'Show Field Keys' to 'Yes'
    See your field keys next to the field number in your group list.

Comment: I couldn't import the letter but it has empty h1 tag